# How can I set an HTML element's ID to equal its inner text with JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple HTML form that allows users to enter a string and, through jQuery, create a "shopping list" item.

For example, a user enters **oranges** in the form:

```
<form id="js-shopping-list-form">
      <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
      <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
      <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>
```

And jQuery generates this snippet:

```
<ul class="shopping-list">
        <li>
            <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
            <div class="shopping-item-controls">
              <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
                <span class="button-label">check</span>
              </button>
              <button class="shopping-item-delete">
                <span class="button-label">delete</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
```

Is there a way to take the string (in this case, "oranges") and turn it into an id  `id="oranges"` inside `<span class="shopping-item></span>`?

Essentially, I'd like for every new `.shopping-item` span to also be assigned a unique identifier so that I can track it easily.

Comment: What happens if someone enters oranges twice?

Comment: What happens if someone enters "orange juice", or any other item with a space in the name?

Comment: If possible, avoid this, and address them as $('.shopping-list .shopping-item').eq(n) to get the nth one etc.

Comment: @MeghanArmes That's a good question––I think @DevlshOne mentioned below that I'll need to use `.uniqueID()` in that case.

Comment: Spelled it wrong in my comment, sorry.  Should have been `uniqueid()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.shopping-item').eq(0).attr('id') = $('.shopping-item').eq(0).text();
```

This assumes that you want to do this for only the first one.  If you need to do this for all items in the `shopping-list`, you can loop through the `.shopping-item` elements and use `this`.

Comment: Now... in the case that `oranges` is entered twice, you'll have duplicate `id`s and an invalid DOM.  In that case, you can add `.uinqueid()` and get a `uuid` style unique `id` for each element.

Comment: It would actually be a cool way to alert the user that they've already got [dupe item] on the list and refuse to add it, I think, but if OP wants to allow it, the method you suggest would be fantastic.

Comment: OK, that's helpful. Sounds like `.uniqueid()` is what I need to use here. Thanks!